# EPiServer 4.61 removing script tags from WYSIWYG editor

Tags: episerver

I know the WYSIWYG editor is not designed for pasting flash video object and script tags into the page but lets say you want to do that... Why does the EPiServer editor strip out the first javascript tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Microsoft editor plugin that does it. It messes up almost all HTML elements.